# Azure Function Context

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am looking to use `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext` to get the `InvocationId` while a function is running, but is there a way to get this while outside of the actual function call.

So if a calling class needs to have some kind of context it can use this. Is it possible?

Comment: An InvocationId is assigned per function invocation. Not really sure how you would expect to access it outside the context of a called function as it does not exist yet

Answer (score 0):

When you run a function you have [ExecutionContext](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function#net-languages-c-f-etc)

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
{
    return req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, context.InvocationId);
}
```

So if you call any method you probably will need to path this id to it. I am not sure if there is any kind of static helper for that.

Comment: I have seen the ExecutionContext but I need to access it outside of the Run method. I can't really assign it to a static as the static is shared among all calls to this function.

Comment: Not really, it uses dependency injection so all kinds of other classes get pulled in that need to know the context to which they were called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to thread that as a parameter through all your calls, trying to solve this with some kind of ambient storage, like `TLS` or `AsyncLocal` is probably not the best approach but it will probably work.

If you don't use async APIs you might get away with:

```
[ThreadLocal]
public static Guid InvocationId;
```

...but if you do use async, you can try:

```
public static AsyncLocal<Guid> InvocationId = new AsyncLocal<Guid>();
```

Good luck!